# I deployed nextjs application when we acess this application in browser getting error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChDT2.png)I deployed nextjs application when we acess this application in browser getting error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I have tried new project in ec2 mahine but faced same issue in nextjs
I am using pm2 and docker both faced same issue